How to fix my modal gallery on how to better improve the succeeding images
I'm still learning JS and wanted to make a small modal gallery with the inside having its own gallery for a brochure for a wedding salon. Below is the link to my Codepen:
Codepen
I managed to open the modal gallery but the 2nd gallery gets messed up and wouldn't play nice. I'm no JavaScript expert yet but I managed this far.
I want the 2nd one to not be all over the place. I tried to code it in earlier but my skills are still lacking.


window.addEventListener("click", init, false);

// Get modal element
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const modal1 = document.getElementById("myModal1");

// Get the button that opens the modal
const mdl = document.getElementById("openModal");
const mdl1 = document.getElementById("openModal1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the image, open the modal
mdl.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

mdl1.onclick = function () {
  modal1.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";

  }
  if (event.target === modal1) {
    modal1.style.display = "none";

  }
};

///////////////

function init(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest(".item")) return;
  let hero = document.querySelector('div[data-pos="0"]');
  let target = e.target.parentElement;
  [target.dataset.pos, hero.dataset.pos] = [
    hero.dataset.pos,
    target.dataset.pos,
  ];
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  height: 100svh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}


.gallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 990px;
  height: 605px;

  &:hover :not(div[data-pos="0"], img) {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  & .item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 175px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.9s, width 0.9s, height 0.9s;

    & img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }

  & div[data-pos="0"] {
    width: 600px;
    height: inherit;
    z-index: 10;
  }
}

div[data-pos="0"] {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
div[data-pos="1"] {
  transform: translate(620px, 0);
}
div[data-pos="2"] {
  transform: translate(815px, 0);
}
div[data-pos="3"] {
  transform: translate(620px, 170px);
}
div[data-pos="4"] {
  transform: translate(815px, 170px);
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .gallery {
    width: 405px;
    height: 660px;

    & .item {
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
    }

    & div[data-pos="0"] {
      width: inherit;
      height: 350px;
      // z-index: 1;
    }
  }

  div[data-pos="0"] {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  div[data-pos="1"] {
    transform: translate(0, 355px);
  }
  div[data-pos="2"] {
    transform: translate(0, 510px);
  }
  div[data-pos="3"] {
    transform: translate(205px, 355px);
  }
  div[data-pos="4"] {
    transform: translate(205px, 510px);
  }
}

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal1 {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: fit-content; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%; /* Adjust as needed */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100px; /* Thumbnail size */
  // margin: 10px;
  transition: transform 0.2s; /* Animation */
}

//////////////
<div class="wrapper">   
<img
      id="openModal"
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578054330576-3f6646e38b1b?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      alt="Open Modal"
      style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px"
    />

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="gallery">
          <!-- Gallery Images Here -->
          <main class="gallery">
            <div class="item" data-pos="0">
              <img
                src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661456395657-049a92e01522?q=80&w=1976&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-pos="1">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580151134699-e0cfbeb763d3?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-pos="2">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549488497-94b52bddac5d?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-pos="3">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523264114838-feca761983c4?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-pos="4">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542764824-4cdbd6c92dbe?q=80&w=2069&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
          </main>

          <!-- Add other images similarly -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trigger Button 2nd -->
    <img
      id="openModal1"
      src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661340932540-c285e730728a?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      alt="Open Modal"
      style="width: 100%; max-width: 300px"
    />

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal modal1">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <div class="gallery">
          <!-- Gallery Images Here -->
          <main class="gallery">
            <div class="item" data-pos="0">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525258946800-98cfd641d0de?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-pos="1">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628046276142-a614ec8c5504?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-pos="2">
              <img
                src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1664530452440-e0cbce3869c0?q=80&w=1972&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-pos="3">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593575620619-602b4ddf6e96?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-pos="4">
              <img
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615164631286-c9a3fd24e3ad?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
              />
            </div>
          </main>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>




You should use real HTML <dialog> element en JS .showModal() method...

@MisterJojo doesn't work or at the very least, it doesn't fix the issue. The problem seems to be coming from the 2nd gallery, it doesn't go back to it's original data-pos-# and stays at data-pos-0 when selected.

OK, yeah. In the meantime, I see this: "2nd gallery gets messed up and wouldn't play nice". Would you edit to explain what this means? "Messed up" and "not playing nicely" are not really very accurate bug reports.

@MisterJojo you have no idea how grateful I am! I will make sure to study this thoroughly before I even implement it on my own. Again, thank you very much, it may not look like much but I am grateful for your help.

@halfer I apologize if my way of conveying data isn't up to par yet. I'll be sure to improve so If you see my inquires again you won't think "what the fuck is this guy saying"
Thank you very much for helping me though. I really appreciate it.

@user25737164: no problem. A good rule of thumb here is to write posts as if they were documentation (contrary to popular opinion, Stack Overflow is not a chatroom or a forum). Good questions (and answers) are kept forever here, so we want them to be reasonably well spelled, have correct case, be well formatted, etc. Folks who have English as a second language are encouraged to install a spelling or grammar checker.

you can do this that way ( with real <dialog> element en JS .showModal() method.


const
  myModalDialog = document.querySelector('#modal-dial')
  ;
document.querySelector('div.wrapper').addEventListener('click', ({target})=>
  {
  if (!target.matches('img[data-modal]')) return
    ;
  myModalDialog.className = target.dataset.modal;
  myModalDialog.showModal();
  })

myModalDialog.addEventListener('click', ({target}) =>
  {
  if (target.matches('.close'))
    {
    myModalDialog.close();
    return; 
    }
  if ( !target.matches('img')) return
    ;
  const 
    small = target.closest('.item')
  , pos   = small.dataset.pos
  , bigg  = small.closest('.gallery').querySelector('.item[data-pos="0"]')
    ;
  if (small===bigg) return
    ;
  small.dataset.pos = '0';
  bigg.dataset.pos  = pos;
  })
* {
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  box-sizing  : border-box;
  }
body {
  height      : 100svh;
  display     : grid;
  place-items : center;
  }
.wrapper img {
  width  : 300px;
  cursor : pointer;
  }
dialog {
  position : relative;
  margin   : auto;
  border   : none;
  padding  : 20px;
  outline  : none;
  }
dialog::backdrop {
  background-color: #7fffd49f;
  }
.gallery {
  position : relative;
  width    : 990px;
  height   : 605px;
  }
.gallery .item:not([data-pos="0"]) {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
.gallery .item {
  position   : absolute;
  width      : 175px;
  height     : 150px;
  overflow   : hidden;
  transition : transform 0.9s, width 0.9s, height 0.9s;
  }
.gallery .item img {
  width  : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  }
.gallery .item[data-pos="0"] {
  width     : 600px;
  height    : inherit;
  transform : translate(0, 0);
  z-index   : 10;
  }
.gallery .item[data-pos="1"] { transform: translate(620px,   0);   }
.gallery .item[data-pos="2"] { transform: translate(815px,   0);   }
.gallery .item[data-pos="3"] { transform: translate(620px, 170px); }
.gallery .item[data-pos="4"] { transform: translate(815px, 170px); }

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .gallery {
    width  : 405px;
    height : 660px;
    }
  .gallery .item {
    width  : 200px;
    height : 150px;
    }
  .gallery .item[data-pos="0"] {
    width  : inherit;
    height : 350px;
    }
  .gallery .item[data-pos="0"] { transform: translate(  0,     0  ); }
  .gallery .item[data-pos="1"] { transform: translate(  0,   355px); }
  .gallery .item[data-pos="2"] { transform: translate(  0,   510px); }
  .gallery .item[data-pos="3"] { transform: translate(205px, 355px); }
  .gallery .item[data-pos="4"] { transform: translate(205px, 510px); }
  }

dialog.modal_0 > article:not(.modal_0) ,
dialog.modal_1 > article:not(.modal_1) {
  display: none;
  }
  
.close {
  color       : #aaa;
  float       : right;
  font-size   : 28px;
  font-weight : bold;
  cursor      : pointer;
  transform   : translate(18px, -24px)
  }
.close:hover { 
  color: black; 
  }
<div class="wrapper">
  <img alt="" data-modal="modal_0"
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578054330576-3f6646e38b1b?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
  >
  <img  alt="" data-modal="modal_1"
    src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661340932540-c285e730728a?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
  >
</div>

<dialog id="modal-dial" class="modal_0">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <article class="gallery modal_0">
    <div class="item" data-pos="0">
      <img
        src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661456395657-049a92e01522?q=80&w=1976&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-pos="1">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580151134699-e0cfbeb763d3?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-pos="2">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549488497-94b52bddac5d?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-pos="3">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523264114838-feca761983c4?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-pos="4">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542764824-4cdbd6c92dbe?q=80&w=2069&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
  </article>

  <article class="gallery modal_1">
    <div class="item" data-pos="0">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525258946800-98cfd641d0de?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-pos="1">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628046276142-a614ec8c5504?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-pos="2">
      <img
        src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1664530452440-e0cbce3869c0?q=80&w=1972&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-pos="3">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593575620619-602b4ddf6e96?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-pos="4">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1615164631286-c9a3fd24e3ad?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D"
      />
    </div>
  </article>

</dialog>



